# mode_rewrite (.htaccess) wrong outcome

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm not sure what's wrong. I use massively rewrite on to domain with various rules with no problem, now here on subdomain the rewritten result point wrong data.

The space is accessible from multiple domains, and I want to switch by hostname to specific subfolder for CSS contents:

```
RewriteEngine on

# - - - shared space / multiple css.*.tld subdomains - - -

# domain 1 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^css\.firstdomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$  fir/$1

# domain 2
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^css\.seconddomain2\.com$
RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$  sec/$1

# *.min.css -> scss.php?file=*
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.min\.css$ scss.php?scss=$1 [QSA]

#
```

First there are rules to rewrite universal `/css/` path to path specific for files for that host, then last line should change `*.min.css` to `scss.php?scss=$1` - so it send the file /without the extension .min.css/ as parameter to php file which then searches for that file with .scss extension to check last modified and either return cached or recompile the source scss file to cached css file

Now I'd expect when I enter: http://css.firstdomain.com/css/first/first.min.css

should rewrite to: http://css.firstdomain.com/scss.php?file=fir/first/first.min.css

but it rewrites to: http://css.firstdomain.com/scss.php?file=fir/first/first.min.css/first/first

So it rewrites it like almost twice for some reason. What might be the reason for this?

There will be problem of some kind with the firs part as entering straight http://css.firstdomain.com/fir/first/first.min.css
rewrites to correct (scss.php?file=fir/first/first).

Answer (score 0):

Oooh found it! I missed the `[L]` (last) flag after rules for each domain, now it works like it should

For completeness, here is the code:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^css\.firstdomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$  fir/$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^(.+)\.min\.css$ scss.php?scss=$1 [QSA,L]
```